# Need to substitute string in the date function using PHP

Tags: php, database, date, for-loop

I have a loop that add one week to the current week as follows,

```
for($b=0; $b < 27; $b++)
{
    $header_week = date('YW',strtotime('+'.$b.' week'));
}
```

This loop output will be,

```
O/P : 201850,201851,201852,201901,201902,201903,....,201924.
```

but instead of adding one week to current week, if i try to add one week to defined string the output as follows,

```
$date = '201848';
for($b=0; $b < 27; $b++)
{
   $date1 = date('YW', strtotime('+'.$b.' week', $date));
}

O/P : 197001,197002,197003,etc....
```

but i need the output like,

```
O/P : 201848,201849,201850,201851,201852,201901,etc..`.
```

How to substitute the string in that date function.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Use `DateTime::setISODate(year, week)` function to get date from year and week then you can keep adding week using `DateTime::add()` function.

Comment: If i trying to add one week to the string using this function $date = '201848';
for($b=0; $b < 27; $b++)
{
   $date1 = date('YW', strtotime('+'.$b.' week', $date));
} but output goes wrong like 197001,197002,197003,etc...

Comment: You can split year and week and then use the function provided above to achieve what you want.

Comment: Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we split YearWeek string to `$year` and `$week` and then create new `DateTime` object. To get current week of given year we use `setISODate` function and then simply run the loop required to keep adding week as per your requirement.

```
$db_date = "201848";
$year = substr($db_date, 0, 4);
$week = substr($db_date, 4);

$dateFromStr = new DateTime();
$dateFromStr->setISODate($year, $week);

if($dateFromStr) {
  for($b=0; $b < 27; $b++)
  {
    $calc_date = clone $dateFromStr;
    $calc_date->add(new DateInterval("P" . $b . "W"));
    $date1 = $calc_date->format("YW");
  }   
}
```

Output:

> 201848, 201849, 201850, 201851, 201852, 201801, 201902, 201903,
>   201904, 201905, 201906, 201907, 201908, 201909..

Comment: This is working perfectly but if you notice the output it display 201801 after 201852 . It should be 201901.